# remove strange characters from a string in python

Tags: python, replace

I have to parse some web data that is fetched from web. It is quite possible that web content can be of different regional languages that I am handling witout any problem. But there are some invalid characters appearing in some string like

> I am wokring
>   8qîÚ4½-ôMºÝCQ´DÉ¬)Q+R±}Ûýï7üÛ²ëlY&53|8ïôóg/^ÿûêþ?ï¯a #ï?¼ºy{5­+B^ß¿ß~¾¿½¦ÓûÆk.c¹~WÚ@ë¤KÈh4rF-G¦!¹ÿ¬¦a~µuÓñµ_»|þì
>   daily statstistics

I have to remove such strange character and onyl extract valid string. I am using python. I am encoding each string with utf-8.

Comment: These are probably not strange characters. You simply use the wrong encoding...

Comment: How do you define a "valid string"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Or a "strange" character? :)

Comment: It is mandateory in many program that I should encode string with utf8

Answer (score 5):

If you mean not-ascii by strange, you could try:

```
import string
"".join(filter(lambda char: char in string.printable, s))
```

Where s is your string.
Here are some string constants you can filter for:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html